# Unable to read data sent from socket server in java

Tags: java, android, sockets, serversocket

i want to make communication between android device and java server.
Server side:

```
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream();
    PrintStream pw = new PrintStream(out);
    pw.print("hello");
    pw.flush();                       
    socket.close();
```

Android client side :

```
   public class connectTask extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        super.run();
            while (true) {
                try {
                Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.0.101", 4444);
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String line = reader.readLine();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        textView.setText(line);
                    }
                });
                socket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {                     
            }}}}
```

and starting thread this way:

```
 thread = new Thread(new connectTask());
 thread.start();
```

the problem is I cannot get anything from java server. I either send or receive data wrong and i can't figure out what's the issue, what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you get any exception on the client app (print the IOException).

Comment: i used printStackTrace() method in catch block and nothing is printed there, also added catch(Exception e) block, did not catch anything either

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks good (may be `String line = ...` should be `final String line = ...`) and IP address and port of Server need to be checked.